# Selenium usage Findelement for list items

Tags: selenium

I need to click on a element on list item to go to next screen .
Html code for that particular element looks like

```
<ul>
<li id="leftSiderBarForm:tokenNoListId">
<li id="leftSiderBarForm:patientCheckinScreenId">
<li id="leftSiderBarForm:checkedInPagingId">
<li id="leftSiderBarForm:priorRegLink">
<a onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function')    {jsfcljs(document.forms['leftSiderBarForm'],'leftSiderBarForm:j_id116,leftSiderBarForm:j_id116,regisType,4,registrationCategory,12','');}return false" href="#">Registration</a>
 </li>
```

I tried using `f1.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Registration")).click()` not able to open locate.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try like This...

```
f1.findElement(By.LinkText("Registration")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
f1.findElement(By.xpath("\\a[text()='Registration']")).click();
```

Comment: your slashes are the other way arount : )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waiting for the element,

```
new WebDriverWait(f1,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Registration"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that there is another link with text Registration available, but it is either hidden or not doing the thing you expect. Anyway, try to make sure that you are getting the correct element.

You might try (from example by @user3283976, but slashed the right way):

```
f1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Registration']")).click();
```

Or

```
//li[@Id='leftSiderBarForm:priorRegLink']/a
```

Or

```
//a[@contains(@onclick, "registrationCategory")]  // make sure that contains is unique
```

Also, when using double quotes and you have double quotes in your string, don't forget to escape them. Ie:

```
f1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@contains(@onclick, \"registrationCategory\")]")
```